# What is "grammar" in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, direct-objects

I am a bit confused about whether "grammar" is an indirect object or a noun. What is the word class of this word

> My students rightly expect me to research my **grammar** before I deliver the lesson.

My = adjective
rightly = adverb
me = object 
 to=  preposition     
      research = verb     
      grammar =     ?????? 
 deliver =  verb         
     the = definite article

Comment: It's an object of "research"

Comment: Also, referring to the *to* before *research* as an **infinitive marker** would be better than referring to it as a preposition.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - or "infinitival subordinator", per Huddleston and Pullum, or even "infinitival verb phrase subordinator", but this is jargon which a learner could or should be spared from. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle My favorite term is actually *particle*. In any case, I think it's useful (for most learners) to know [when "to" is a preposition and when it is the infinitive marker](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103529/when-is-to-a-preposition-and-when-the-infinitive-marker).

Comment: As to the meaning of "to research my grammar" I'm a bit astonished. I would expect that a teacher who gives grammar lessons knows his grammar. A bit funny if such a teacher has to study his grammar before he begins a lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Grammar" is the direct object of the verb "research".  It's also a noun.

(Subjects, direct objects, and indirect objects are almost always nouns.)

Comment: and what do you think about my answers ? are they correct?

Comment: They're all correct.  Note that "me" is the object of "expect", but it's also a pronoun.

Comment: There are two different ways to look at each word: its *part of speech*, and its *syntactic role*.  *Part of speech* means what kind of word it is, regardless of what sentence you use it in: "grammar" will be a noun in every sentence.  *Syntactic role* means what the word is doing in a particular sentence: "grammar" can be the subject ("Grammar is fun."), the direct object ("I hate grammar."),  or part of a prepositional phrase ("The Internet taught me about grammar.")

Comment: Note that some words can have more than one part of speech.  For example, "access" was originally a noun, meaning "the ability to get to something".  "I can't reach this server.  I don't have access."  However, we've also borrowed it to use it as a verb: "I can't access the server."